# How do I encode a classical vector into the input qubits?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, quantum-state

Does anyone know how to encode a classical vector into a quantum state? For instance, I would like to encoder a classical vector $(0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.9)$ into 2 qubits by adding some quantum gates on 2 $|0\rangle$ starting states. Any program package including Qiskit, pyquil, cirq... is fine.

Comment: while there are common, "standard" ways to do this, I would note that in principle you can encode information however you like in the quantum state. You are not in principle bounded to encode it into the amplitudes

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look for quantum amplitude encoding strategies. A nice and practical tutorial (with reference to Qiskit) is the following one by Maria Schuld:

https://medium.com/qiskit/building-the-worlds-smallest-quantum-classifier-7da7cd845b84

Interesting (but more advanced) articles are also:

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-40439-3

https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.02085

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to normalize your vector $x$ to have an Euclidian norm equal one, i.e.

$$
||x||=||(0,0.1,0.4,0.9)|| = \sqrt{0^2 + 0.1^2 +0.4^2+0.9^2} = \sqrt{0.98}
$$

So, your vector representing a quantum state is
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{0.98}}(0,0.1,0.4,0.9).
$$

Now, you can apply methods described in [this thread](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12540/how-to-prepare-an-arbitrary-two-qubit-state/12549#12549).