# How to find a quantum circuit to generate a target state?

Tags: quantum-state, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

I am starting in Quantum Computing, but I am pretty lost, sorry... let's say I need to design a quantum circuit to generate some given quantum states in Dirac's notation, as in the following example, or any other (not asking you to solve this one):

$$ |⟩= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|010⟩ + \frac{1}{2}|101⟩$$

What should I do to perform the right calculations and get which quantum gates I need to use?
Some readings or step-by-step examples you can provide, so, I can start learning?

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12540/how-to-prepare-an-arbitrary-two-qubit-state/12549#12549. Especially the last answer is relevant for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split tasks like this into two steps.

1. Make *any* state with the right amplitudes. Make a state that has the amplitude $\sqrt{3}/2$.
2. Use NOT and CNOT gates to change what the amplitudes are assigned to, until they're assigned to the right thing.